# Reference worker relative to JavaScript file

Tags: webpack, web-worker, worker-loader

I'm using `webpack` to put together a project which uses [`Web Workers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). To accomplish this, I'm using the [`worker-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) loader.

I've made a [minimal plunk](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/4brcPd9N5KfUhcfq?preview) to demonstrate my environment (I'll also paste the code below for posterity).

The problem is, the resolution of the worker file isn't behaving as expected. If I launch `index.html` (I'm serving the root folder with an HTTP server), it can naturally resolve `../dist/TestMain.js`, but it tries to resolve `TestWorker.js` from `./` relative to `index.html`. I'd like it to resolve from `./` relative to `TestMain.js`.

I've tried adding `output.publicPath = "./"`, but that didn't help. I've searched the documentation (and `worker-loader`'s documentation) for similar options, but haven't found anything that I can say is relevant (I could be wrong).

Normally, I'd be all for using `resolve.alias`, but the output should be able to be dropped into any folder (the main JS file and worker JS file would remain together in the same folder) referable by the HTML page.

I also saw I can in-line the worker, but I'd like to avoid that since it blobs the worker (can cause other kinds of referencing problems).

Are there options I'm missing to enable relative referencing, or a workaround I've missed?

Here's the structure:

```
Project
 |- dist
 |   |- TestMain.js
 |   |- TestWorker.js
 |- src
 |   |- workers
 |   |   |- TestWorker.js
 |   |- index.js
 |- test
 |   |- index.html
 |- webpack.config.js
```

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "TestMain.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: "MyLib",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/workers"),
        ],
        use: {
          loader: "worker-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].js"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I'll share my other files if you want, but it *does work* if the worker file is in the same folder as `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `publicPath` option for worker-loader:

```
        use: {
          loader: "worker-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].js",
            publicPath: "/dist"
          }
        }
```

Alternatively, you might consider adding a step to your build process that copies static assets, including index.html, to the dist folder.

Comment: Would this work for `publicPath: "./"`? The idea is to have both JavaScript files in the same directory, regardless of where (and most likely it will _not_ be in `/dist`). So, regardless of where they have been deployed, I want my `TestMain.js` to be able to reference `TestWorker.js` _from the same directory_. I want to expect `./` to be relative to `TestMain.js`, not relative to wherever `index.html` lives, which is how it currently works.

Comment: @TheJim01 I've only now inspected your plunk. I set it up (btw, Idk how plunk works, but I had to install all packages manually — your package.json was of little help). I noticed you are trying to postMessage the whole event, which results in `DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.`. You should only post serializable data. In the `onmessage` handler, you can access what you passed as argument to `postMessage` in `event.data`.

Comment: The worker URL (and by extension, worker-loader's `publicPath`) are relative to the HTML requesting it, not the JS script. Resolving paths relative to your sources is up to Webpack. So by setting `publicPath: '/dist/'` I got it to work for /test/index.html as well as its copy at /index.html. I couldn't make it work for /test/foo/index.html though, but that's another question.